# Can JPA handle interface references?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have the following 3 entities:

- entity class A implements interface X
- entity class B implements interface X
- entity class C

Where I could like entity class C to be able to hold a reference to an entity of type X, that is: either A or B.

Is it possible to do this without having two reference fields in C, like:

@ManyToOne private C parent;

Or do I need to have one reference for each implementation of C and do the assignment myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. JPA doesn't define persistence for fields/properties of interface types. JDO is the only persistence specification to allow that.

Only thing you could do is have a common base class, but that may be impossible with your model.

Answer (score 1):

Not defined in JPA spec, but if using EclipseLink you can use a @VariableOneToOne mapping for this.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Interfaces